# Symfony Unable to find template "BlogBundle::inicio.html.twig"

Tags: php, symfony, views

Estoy aprendiendo symfony 3.4 y estoy intentando linkear una ruta con una vista. Cuando ejecuto el programa usando la ruta:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/home
```

Me genera el siguente: ***Unable to find template "BlogBundle::inicio.html.twig"***

Mi archivo de routing.yml es el siguiente:

```
blog:
    resource: "@BlogBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:    /

app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
```

Mi controlador es el siguiente:

```
<?php

    namespace BlogBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

    class DefaultController extends Controller
    {
         /**
          * @Route("/home",name="home_route")
          *  @Method({"GET"})
          */
         public function indexAction()
         {
            //esta sentencia funciona
            //return new Response('<html><body>hola mundo</body></html>' );

            //
            return $this->render('BlogBundle::inicio.html.twig');
         }

    }
```

Mi archivo `inicio.html.twig` es el siguiente:

```
Hello World!
```

Si alguien me puede orientar sobre como solucionar este inconveniente o alguna sugerencia sera bien recibida, estoy un poco complicado y recien comienzo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede indicar donde tienes el archivo incio.html.twig? si no esta BlogBundle/config/resources/views

puede que ese sea el problema.

**Edito:**

El problema es que no se estaba poniendo de forma correcta la ruta:

`BlogBundle::inicio.html.twig` es correcto cuando esta en la carpeta views, pero si se quiere poner en una carpeta "Default" hay que poner `BlogBundle:Default:inicio.html.twig`.

Comment: Hola Sergio, el archivo se encuentra en  BlogBundle/config/resources/views/Default    Igualmente pude resolverlo ubicando el archivo en la carpeta app/resouces/views/ creando una subcarpeta, no se si es la mejor solución pero fue la que me ayudo a salir de paso

Comment: @CristianBudzicz si, es correcto pero te cuento algo, cuando pones `BlogBundle::inicio.html.twig` el `::` significa que esta en la raíz de views,, si quieres ponerlo en la carpeta Default tienes que poner `BlogBundle:Default:inicio.html.twig`. Es así como funciona.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!